# How to represent elements from $\bar{E}=E/Z(E)$ in the form $(a|b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, coding-theory, quantum-mechanics, quotient-group

From https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9608006

### Background

The group $E$ of tensor products $\pm w_{1} \otimes \dots \otimes w_{n}$ and $\pm i w_{1} \otimes \dots \otimes w_{n}$, where each $w_{j}$ is one of $I, X, Y, Z$ describes the possible errors in $n$ qubits. $E$ has order $2^{2n+2}$.

$E$ has centre $Z(E)=\langle iI \rangle $

$\bar{E}$ is the quotient group $\bar{E}=E/Z(E)$. $\bar{E}$ is a binary vector space of order $2^{2n}$.

Elements of $\bar{E}$ are written $(a|b)=(a_{1} \dots a_{n}|b_{1} \dots b_{n})$ and which is equipped with the inner product $((a|b),(a'|b'))=a.b' + a'.b$

### My Question

It is my understanding that elements of the quotient group $\bar{E}$ must have the form $\bar{e_{i}}=e_{i}\langle iI \rangle=${$iw_{1}\otimes \dots \otimes w_{n},-iw_{1}\otimes \dots \otimes w_{n}, w_{1}\otimes \dots \otimes w_{n}, -w_{1}\otimes \dots \otimes w_{n}$  }

However, I am not seeing how this corresponds to the form that elements are supposed to take in $\bar{E}$, which is $(a|b)$?

In the coset notation, each element appears to have 4 terms, but in the concatenated notation, it appears to be two $n$ length vectors concatenated together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding how they relate, there are two main points to make. Point 1 is technical, making a correction about the elements of the quotient group. Point 2 somewhat intuitive rather than technical, by digging into what the representations mean.

1. The center consists of four elements, which correspond to multiplication by the constants $1,-1,i,-i$. Considering $E / \Xi (E)$ is basically just eliminating those constants out front, so we don’t have to keep considering them. So we just have to think about elements that are essentially of the form
   $$w_1 \otimes \dots \otimes w_n.$$
   (Looking towards the next part, it is in this way that we start only thinking about bit-flip and phase-flip errors.)
2. To relate $w_1 \otimes \dots \otimes w_n$ to $(a | b)$, consider what each is keeping track of.

- The term $w_1 \otimes \dots \otimes w_n$ is of length $n$, and each $w_i$ can be one of four things (specifically, one of $I,\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z$). So this is a set of $(2^2)^n = 2^{2n}$ elements keeping track of the possible bit-flip and phase-flip errors.
- The term $(a|b)$ is keeping track of the possible $\sigma_x$ errors through the binary vector $a$, and the possible $\sigma_z$ errors through the binary vector $b$. Even though its length $2n$ instead of $n$, we can see that since all entries of $a$ and $b$ are either $0$ or $1$ that there are $2^{(2n)} = 2^{2n}$ of them, again representing all possible bit-flip and phase-flip errors.

In summary, $(a|b)$ is a way of representing the elements of $E/\Xi(E)$ that separates the bit-flip and phase-flip errors, as opposed to compacting them together in each $w_i$ of the tensor product representation.

Comment: Thank you! So then if the quotient group $E/ \Xi(E)$ is eliminating the constants out front, meaning that this is an abelian group, where $E$ is not an abelian group. Would this mean that a stabilizer group would be a subgroup of $\bar{E}$ as opposed to a subgroup of $E$ as I had previously assumed?

Comment: @am567 I think technically yes, but intuitively it’s saying “yeah we know there are these floating constants out front, but if we mod them out then nothing major gets lost, so let’s do that to reduce the complexity of what we’re looking at”. As in, it doesn’t make sense to write down a bunch of constants if they don’t affect the main structure of focus :)